# How to convert a 720° ".ts" video recorded with an AllieCam360?

Tags: mp4, conversion, file-formats, 360video

I have an AllieCam camera to record 720 videos 360x2 lenses.

The format it use is `.ts` and the program requires you to login online. Now the manufacturers drop the business and the web site is offline.

How can I now convert the videos to mp4?

I tried a lot of converters but no one solve the problem. If one of them managed to convert to mp4 then I only obtained a sphere with half of the video.

Comment: Your link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

[FFmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html) can see both views as separate video streams.

You can remux the file to MP4 simply by using

```
ffmpeg -i input.ts -c copy -map 0 output.mp4
```

Hopefully, your video editor can work with distinct streams, else they will need to be combined in some way.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer,, The code that you give me, convert the file in to an .mp4 file, but still show only the sphere not the video uncompressed, that is supposed to be wider in 4k resolution
I don´t have an idea of How they do that, I mean why I only can see one side of the camera and not both sides?

Comment: I solved to extract the two videos with the following lines:

ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:2 -map 0:0 -c copy output.mp4     (this for the front video

ffmpeg -i input.ts -map 0:2 -map 0:1 -c copy output.mp4     (this for the rear video)

Thank you Gyan you give the clue